# How do I take apart and fix this shower head?

Tags: repair, water, shower, leak

After not being used for 3 weeks, most of the nozzles in this shower head got clogged by limescale. When I turned on the shower, the plastic housing for the nozzles bulked up under pressure and blew around the sides. Most of the water came out where the plastic part with the nozzles meets the chrome part.

I took the shower head off, and tried prying the nozzle part off by sticking a knife through the small slit between it and the chrome part. I couldn’t take it off without using too much pressure and risking breaking it.

Is there a way to take this apart and fix it? If it can’t be taken apart, would it be sufficient to inject silicone or a similar product in the slit between the two parts in order to seal it?

[image: nozzles side]
[image: top side of shower head]
[image: detail of slit]
[image: top]

Comment: Indeed. My bad.

Comment: Injecting silicone isn’t likely a permanent fix. Hey, if it’s already not working, you can’t make it any worse by prying on it a bit harder and trying to get it apart.